# MUI5 theme aware sx prop and type checking

Tags: typescript, material-ui

When using the sx prop and leveraging theme aware properties in TypeScript. Is type checking happening? How can I confirm this?

Comment: Last time I check, you can't. You probably want to file a feature request on MUI repo, I also want to have something like [this](https://twitter.com/karoljmajewski/status/1303827023383662592/photo/1) so when you press Ctrl + Space to force display autosuggestion, it shows something like `primary.main` | `primary.secondary`....

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can not.

As suggested by @NearHuscarl comment, I fill up a feature request about that.

You can follow it by this link: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32656

If you need the Typescript check on the color value, you can always stick with the `theme.palette` property usage.